# Dimension and Surjectivity proof

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to know how to prove the statement: If $T: V \rightarrow\ W$ is surjective, then $\dim(W) \le \dim (V)$.

I am thinking about proof by contradiction...but don't really have a rigorous proof other than intuition.

Comment: Use the Rank-Nullity Theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you very much! I see, we can derive the conclusion very nicely using the fact that $dim (Image (T)) = dim (W)$ and $dim (ker (T)) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ be a basis of $V$. Let $w\in W$, there exists $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=w$ by surjectivity of $T$, now $v$ can be written as
$$ v=v_1e_1+\cdots+v_ne_n $$
so
$$ w=T(v)=v_1T(e_1)+\cdots+v_nT(e_n). $$
This means that the family $(T(e_1),\ldots,T(e_n))$ generates $W$, so $n\geqslant\dim W$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know where to apply the hypothesis :)